# How to make the notification disappeared after the user have clicked on it

Tags: android

Please take a look at my code:

```
package com.yarin.android.Examples_04_23;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity01 extends Activity {
    Button m_Button1;

    //声明通知（消息）管理器
    NotificationManager m_NotificationManager;
    Intent m_Intent;
    PendingIntent m_PendingIntent;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //初始化NotificationManager对象
        m_NotificationManager = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //获取按钮对象
        m_Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);


        //点击通知时转移内容
        m_Intent = new Intent(Activity01.this, Activity02.class);
        //主要是设置点击通知时显示内容的类
        m_PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Activity01.this, 0, m_Intent, 0);


        m_Button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Notification m_Notification = new Notification();
                //设置通知在状态栏显示的图标
                m_Notification.icon = R.drawable.img1;
                //当我们点击通知时显示的内容
                m_Notification.tickerText = "Button1通知内容...........";
                //通知时发出默认的声音
                m_Notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                //设置通知显示的参数
                m_Notification.setLatestEventInfo(Activity01.this, "Button1", "Button1通知", m_PendingIntent);
                //可以理解为执行这个通知
                m_NotificationManager.notify(0, m_Notification);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

When a user click on the button `click` , a notification will appear on the application bar. However, the notification will stay there **for ever** after a user have click on it 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Notification notification = new Notification();
 notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

From the docs

"Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user"

Answer (score 5):

Just add a line in your m_Button1 click listener right after :

```
m_Notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

m_Notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```